# I am getting the error: np.append(Image()) TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'imgtype'

Tags: python, image, numpy, processing

I have this code snippet in python:

```
for i in range(N_SLICES):
    np.append(Image())
if frame is not None:
    t1 = time.clock()
    SlicePart(frame, Images, N_SLICES)
    for i in range(N_SLICES):
        print (i)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
np.append(Image())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'imgtype'
```

with an error previous to it! but I found a similar to it but how can I solve it please

this is a project that I copied and added to it in the github repository named "vision race" buut I have unified the three files in one

Comment: `Image()` doesn't match its docs.  But the use of `np.append` is wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the following project:

https://github.com/CRM-UAM/VisionRace/

I can see that the `Image` class is defined inside `Image.py`:

https://github.com/CRM-UAM/VisionRace/blob/master/Repo/Image.py

Make sure you are importing `Image` from there and not somewhere else such as `tkinter`:

```
from Image import Image
```

Update: You appear to be importing `Image` from `tkinter`:

I can see that `imgtype` is a required argument in the constructor

https://kite.com/python/docs/tkinter.Image